# Python Parse single line of XML

Tags: python, html, xml, scraper

What im trying to do is make a scraper and there is a login page, im filling two out of three values needed to get on the next page

the scraper needs a username,password and then the token,

im autofilling the username and password and ive narrowed the html response down to the one input tag in python.

The tags code is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="licence[_csrf_token]" value="SOME RANDOM CHECKSUM" id="licence__csrf_token" />
```

is there any way of getting this and by the way the checksum is dynamic as in it changes length.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting this"? Also, what tools have you used to extract the input tag from the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is one good way to parse arbitrary HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<input type="hidden" 
                     name="licence[_csrf_token]" 
                     value="SOME RANDOM CHECKSUM"
                     id="licence__csrf_token" />'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
print soup.input['value']
```